# Wrapping a field value with <p>

Tags: theming

I am using  the Drupal 7's Bartik theme.

It wraps with `<p>` the content-type fields that are set as "long text," but not the fields that are set as "text."

Where do I change this so that it wraps every field with `<p>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
node--<content-type>.tpl.php
```

Check out the discussion for how to active template suggestions at the theme level: [Drupal 7 page template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1035656).